# Growth of the coefficients of the inversion of the $j$-invariant function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, elliptic-curves, fourier-analysis, modular-forms

We have the $j$-invariant defined as

I have that
$$
j(\tau)=\frac{1}{q}+\sum_{k\geq 0}c_kq^k,
$$
where $q=e^{-2\pi t}$ ($\tau=it$) and $c_k\sim e^{4\pi\sqrt{k}}/(k^{3/4}\sqrt{2})$.

The inversion formula for the $j$-invariant is
$$
q=j^{-1}+\sum_{k\geq 2}d_kj^{-k}.
$$

Thus, I would like to know some upper bound or asymptotic formula for $d_k$.

Any hint or reference?

Comment: Have you see this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02725.pdf)? You might be able to find what you are looking for there.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A091406](https://oeis.org/A091406) entry probably has the information you are looking for. The series is $q = 1/j + 744/j^2 + 750420/j^3 + 872769632/j^4 + \cdots$

Comment: @Somos Thanks for your answer.  Actually, I would like to find an explicit upper bound for $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{kd_k}{(1728)^{k+1}}$ in terms of $1/(q-q_0)$, for $q_0=e^{-2\pi}$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please edit your question to include this vital piece of context for everyone to see.

Comment: @Somos Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Your series $\,\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{kd_k}{(1728)^{k+1}}\,$ does **not** depend on $\,q\,$ so how can you expect an upper bound "in terms of $1/(q-q_0)$"? Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Dear @Somos sorry for my inexperience in this web site, I tried to make things simpler and I made some confusion. I think now the question is completely well-posed. But I don't know if I should edit or create another question. Sorry.

Comment: In general, you should not edit a question so that previous answers are no longer comprehensible. In such a case, it's generally better to ask a new question.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Agreed. I think a new question is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks @JoeSilverman I will do it right now and sorry again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A066396

There's a formula there that gives an approximation  of the form (in your notation)
$$
d_k \sim A \cdot (-1)^{k+1}\cdot B^k / k^{3/2}
$$
where $A\approx1943.54943\dots$
and $B\approx2311.3945621\dots\,$.

Comment: No, that is a different inverse where $t := q^2 j = q + 744 q^2 + 196884 q^3 + \cdots $ implies $ q = t - 744t^2 + 910188t^3 + \cdots.$

Answer (score 4):

Extended comment: Some analysis I've done recently in free probability theory gives the compositional inverse of a Laurent series of the form

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + a_1 + a_2 z + a_3z^2 + \cdots$$

as

$$f^{(-1)}(z) =\frac{1}{z} + \frac{a_1}{z^2} + \frac{a_1^2+a_2}{z^3} + \frac{a_3+3a_1a_2+a_1^3}{z^4}+\cdots,$$

where the numerator polynomials are given in OEIS [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264) and are related to noncrossing partitions, Dyck lattice paths, and other combinatorial constructs.

This supports Somos' claim that OEIS A091406 gives the inverse of the j-invariant.

Comment: I had forgotten that this result is also found on p. 11 of "Modular Matrix Models" by 
Yang-Hui He and Vishnu Jejjala (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0307293.pdf). I arrived at it recently (once again after encountering it several years ago) through a different method while relating an identity connected to a Virasoro group action presented by A. Alexandov in "Enumerative geometry, tau-functions and Heisenberg–Virasoro algebra" to earlier notes of mine.

Answer (score 0):

$j(\tau)=J(e^{2i\pi \tau})$, since $J(q)\in q^{-1}+\Bbb{Z}[[q]]$ then in formal series $$f(s)=J^{-1}(1/s)=\sum_{k\ge 1} d_k s^k \text{ is in }\Bbb{Z}[[s]] \tag{1}$$

$f^{-1}(q)=1/J(q)$ is surjective from $|q|< 1$ to $\Bbb{C}$ and locally biholomorphic away from $J(q)\in 0,1728,i\infty$. **Whence in the branch where $f(0)=0$ then $f$ is analytic for $|q|<1/1728$**, and it will be given by the series $(1)$.

The radius of convergence is $1/1728$ and
$f'(1/1728)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{k\, d_k}{1728^k}$ doesn't converge, this follows from that $J'(i)=0\implies \lim_{s\to 1/1728^-}f'(s)=\infty$.

To get an upper bound on the $d_k$, let $m(y)=\sup_{\Im(\tau)>y} |1/j(\tau)|$.
For $|s|<m(y)$ we'll have $J^{-1}(1/s)<e^{-2\pi y}$ so that $|d_k|  \le m(y)^{-k-1}  e^{-2\pi y}$ whenever $m(y)< 1/1728$. [A numerical check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2FAbs%5B1728*KleinInvariantJ%5B2*i%2Bx%5D%5D+from+x%3D0+to+1) shows that $m(2)< 10^{-5}$.

The monodromy group of $j^{-1}(s)$ and $f(s)$ is interesting:

- in the branch where $j^{-1}(\infty)= i\infty$ when rotating around $\infty$ it transforms $j^{-1}(s)$ to $j^{-1}(s)-1=\pmatrix{1&-1\\0&1}j^{-1}(s)$.
- In the branch where $j^{-1}(1728)=i$ when rotating around $1728$ it transforms $j^{-1}(s)$ to $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0} j^{-1}(s)$.
- In the branch where $j^{-1}(0))=e^{2i\pi/3}$ when rotating around $0$ it transforms $j^{-1}(s)$ to $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&1} j^{-1}(s)$.
- In the branch where $j^{-1}(\infty)=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}i\infty=a/c$ it gets different, rotating around $\infty$ transforms $j^{-1}(s)$ to $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \pmatrix{1&-1\\0&1} \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^{-1} j^{-1}(s)$. Whence in the branch such that $f(0)=\exp(-2i\pi a/d)$ then $f(s) = \exp(-2i\pi j^{-1}(s))$ isn't analytic at $0$ anymore.